# Sort array of datesTime

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, datetime

I have a array of objects that have a property of date adn time, and im trying to sort by desc or asc, but it doesnt work, it gets all mix up da array.

My code:

```
var myDateTime = [
  {date: "2016-06-08 18:10:00"},
  {date: "2016-04-26 20:01:00"},
  {date: "2017-02-06 14:38:00"},
  {date: "2017-01-18 17:30:21"},
  {date: "2017-01-18 17:24:00"}
];

var sortIt = myDateTime.sort(function(a, b) {
    return new Date( a.date ) < new Date( b.date );
});
```

Comment: Never parse strings with the Date constructor (or Date.parse, they are equivalent for parsing) as parsing is largely implementation dependent and inconsistent. `new Date( a.date )` returns an invalid date in Safari. Also, the *sort* function should return a value that is less than zero, zero, or more than zero. Returning a boolean will be converted to 0 or 1, so will not sort correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Sort requires a value of 0, 1 or -1.

```
adate = new Date(a.date)
bdate = new Date(b.date)
return adate > bdate ? -1 : adate < bdate ? 1 : 0
```

or even simpler,

```
array.sort(function(a,b){
  return new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this should do the trick:

```
   var sortIt = myDateTime.sort(function(a, b) {
                        var dateA = new Date( a.date );
                        var dateB = new Date( b.date );
                        return dateA < dateB  ? -1 :( dateA > dateB ? 1 : 0);
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

With [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date, you could use just [`String#localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare).

```js
var myDateTime = [{ date: "2016-06-08 18:10:00" }, { date: "2016-04-26 20:01:00" }, { date: "2017-02-06 14:38:00" }, { date: "2017-01-18 17:30:21" }, { date: "2017-01-18 17:24:00" }];

myDateTime.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.date.localeCompare(b.date);
});

console.log(myDateTime);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```